# Functions of Random variables and Expectations

Tags: probability-theory

I have an equation which is the sum of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that:
\begin{align}
Z = X + Y E[Z] 
\end{align}

I know assuming independence of $X$ and $Y$ without the $E[Z]$ we can simply express the MGF of $Z$ as the product of the MGFs of $X$ and $Y$.

Is there a way to derive the MGF of $Z$ in the problem above?

Comment: "...we can simply express the MGF of $Z$ as the product of the MGFs of $X$ and $Y$..." This is true under an extra condition that is not mentioned in your question: independence.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified in the original question but I am assuming that the two variables are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $Z=X+Y\mathbb EZ$ then:$$M_Z(t)=\mathbb Ee^{tZ}=\mathbb Ee^{t(X+Y\mathbb EZ)}=\mathbb Ee^{tX}e^{tY\mathbb EZ}=\mathbb Ee^{tX}\mathbb Ee^{tY\mathbb EZ}=M_X(t)M_Y(t\mathbb EZ)$$

The fourth equality is based on independence (if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then so are $e^{tX}$ and $e^{tY\mathbb EZ}$).

Answer (score 0):

See Casella & Berger, theorem **2.13.35**

*for any constant a and b, the mgf of the random variable $Y=aX+b$ is given by*:

$$e^{bt}M_X(at)$$

Once you arrive here you can treat the problem as usual (if the variables are independent), writing the $M_Z(t)=M_X(t)\cdot M_Y(E(Z)\cdot t)$